# Xmx is 3072m but Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() returns 59mb

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-size

I am using eclipse EE in ubuntu by downloading the .tar.gz file from eclipse website and extracting in my home directory. I set the -Xmx to 3072m in the eclipse.ini. Here it is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms2048m
-Xmx3072m
```

But when I am trying to see my total memory by

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

It is returning 62193664 that is 59mb. I also tried to launch eclipse from terminal setting vmagrs, but nothing changed. I don't know what is happening. How can I set the heap size? My total ram is 4gb and I using 64bit Ubuntu with 64bit eclipse. Any information will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` does not return the maximum allowed heap size.

2) I'm not sure how do you run `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` but I guess you do that from within your Eclipse in a Java application. In this case you execute the call in another JVM which does not inherit properties from your `eclipse.ini` file. If you want to determine the initial and max heap size for it you can go to `Run->Run Configurations...`. Click on your current run configuration and in the right pane click on the `Arguments` tab. There you may specify the VM arguments, e.g.:

```
-Xms64m
-Xmx1024m
```

Afterwards you may continue experimenting with the `Runtime`. `eclipse.ini` configures the resources for the Eclipse IDE not for the Java application that you run.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion is really helpful. Setting -vm option from run configuration is working. But Runtime is giving same old value. But the code is now working and allocating memory space for 1000000000 dimension boolean array. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi! The totalMemory() does not print the max heap size. You can find numerous samples how to do more verbose printing. Example: http://itspice.net/cms/java/how-to-print-java-jvm-heap-size-and-memory-usage-info-in-runtime

Answer (score 1):

In short, `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` is useless, it returns the size of one GC generation.

This thread has an explanation: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-use/2008-December/000318.html

Comment: For testing Xmx I am trying to allocate memory of a boolean array with dimension 1000000000. It is giving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space from eclipse. But if I execute the java code command line setting java -Xmx3072m it is working. But from eclipse it is not working. I had set the -vm of eclipse.ini to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java. But nothing changed. I have no explanation of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. So the solution is setting VM Arguments from Run->Run Configurations in eclipse. I had set it to -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m and now the Runtime totalMemory() is returning 3087007744 that is 2944MB in 4gb ram with 64 bit Ubuntu 10.10 and 64 bit JVM.